# SQL query class has no persistent fields in the SELECT

Tags: postgresql, jdo

```
 static void go() {
    PersistenceManager pm = null;
    Transaction tx = null;
    try {
        pm = new JDOFactory().getFactory().getPersistenceManager();
        tx = pm.currentTransaction();
        Query q = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL", "select * from \"OAUTHTEMP\" where \"O_AUTH_TOKEN\"=:oAuthToken and \"O_AUTH_VERIFIED\"=:oAuthVerified");
        Map params = new HashMap();
        params.put("oAuthToken", "08f727ab-7132-426c-8fc2-9ce2b30ebf9d");
        params.put("oAuthVerifier", "C3ExGzv+cAQkOqwL4oY94fZhDyVLyo/0H31w8F3q+YYLSBDxl2YARcglqPuKcsfT");
        List<OAuthTemp> result = (List<OAuthTemp>) q.executeWithMap(params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my function to fetch all data on the basis of token and verifier but I am getting the exception below:

> SQL query class has no persistent fields in the SELECT : select * from "OAUTHTEMP" where "O_AUTH_TOKEN"=:oAuthToken and "O_AUTH_VERIFIED"=:oAuthVerified
>   org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: SQL query class has no persistent fields in the SELECT : select * from "OAUTHTEMP" where "O_AUTH_TOKEN"=:oAuthToken and "O_AUTH_VERIFIED"=:oAuthVerified
>       at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery.prepareForExecution(SQLQuery.java:994)
>       at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery.executeWithMap(SQLQuery.java:818)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeInternal(JDOQuery.java:369)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeWithMap(JDOQuery.java:276)
>       at com.xenonstack.demo.test.Test.go(Test.java:61)
>       at com.xenonstack.demo.test.Test.main(Test.java:40)

My OAuthTemp class is this
[OauthTemp class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctX29.png).

Comment: kindly accept the answer if it fixes your problem. If it doesn't then post back as to what effect it has

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a query with a parameter called `oAuthVerified` yet are providing a value for `oAuthVerifier`. Perhaps if you fix that it would work?